# Django - Reverse with special character

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

When I want use argument with specials characters in reverse, I have this error :

Reverse for 'l_s.views.my_pro' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'namep': u'\xe9 \xe9 \xe9  sds ( \xe9zacd '}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P\w+)$']

My View :

```
def createPro(request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid() :
        name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
        return redirect(reverse(my_pro, kwargs={'namep': name}))

def my_pro(request,namep):
    pro = Pro.objects.get(name=namep)
    ...
```

My Template :

```
...
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'createPro' %}" class="form-signin">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-3">
                {{ form.name|bootstrap }}
        </div>
...
```

My URL :

```
url(r'^create-pro$', 'createPro', name='createPro'),
url(r'^(?P<namep>\w+)$','my_pro', name="mypro"),
```

**I have this error when the variable "name" in method "createPro" contains special character. For this example, name = "é é é  sds ( ézacd "**

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem - but URI can only contain ASCII characters (see [RFC-2396](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396.html))

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: unrelated IRI can contain non-ascii characters (see [rfc 3987](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987#page-8)). Common application is [IDNA](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5891)

Comment: You are right, but as far as django in concerned you still need to URL encode it (support for IDN is coming in 1.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test case is `name = "é é é sds ( ézacd "`, while your regexp for the view is `url(r'^(?P<namep>\w+)$'`. `' '` and `(` are not matched by `\w`, so that regexp does not match. Try it with `"ééésdsézacd"`, or update your regexp to allow the characters you want to allow in the name.

Code review makes it appear that the Django URL resolver uses the `re.UNICODE` flag, so I would expect `'é'` etc to match `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to include unicode character in you url. try this: [how to have unicode characters in django url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514455/how-to-have-unicode-characters-in-django-url)