# Using persian unicode in django url

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, python-unicode

Hi I want to use persian chracters in my url like:

localhost:8000/products/سامسونگ-گلکسی-اس22

that means in english:

localhost:8000/products/samsung-galaxy-s22

I writted this for slugify and slug field:

```
slug = md.SlugField(default='', null=False, blank=True, max_length=200, unique=True, allow_unicode=True,
                    verbose_name='عنوان در url')
```

and,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my url path:

```
path('<slug:slug>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
```

it's working good and slugifies the title of product but when I want to use it the appliction returns 500 internal error
and when I put an english title for product instead of the persian one the app works normally but with an english slug

> Note: I imported models as md

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514455/how-to-have-unicode-characters-in-django-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use <str:slug> instead of <slug:slug> in your url path cause slug only matches ascii chars, not persian letters.

[Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51581700/13635627)